# recyclerview with two viewtypes not chaning viewtype

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-authentication

In my android firebase chat app, I want to use recyclerview to display chatlist according to the type of message i.e either incoming or outgoing

Let me first tell you the firebase data structure

```
<ConversationId>
    <MsgId>
       text :"Hello"
       timestamp :<timestamp>
       sender :<sender's uid>
       receiver :<receiver's uid>
```

Following is my adapter class

```
public class MultiViewTypeAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

        private List<SingleChatList> chatList;
        int total_types;


        public class incoming extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public TextView message,time;
            //public CircleImageView dp;

            public incoming(View view)
            {
                super(view);
                message=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                time=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp_text);
            }
        }

        public class outgoing extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public TextView message,time;
            //public CircleImageView dp;

            public outgoing(View view)
            {
                super(view);
                message=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message_text_view);
                time=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp_text_view);
            }
        }



        public MultiViewTypeAdapter(List<SingleChatList> data) {
            this.chatList = data;
            total_types = chatList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view;
            switch (viewType) {
                case 0:
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.msg_incoming_bubble, parent, false);
                    return new incoming(view);
                case 1:
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.msg_outgoing_bubble, parent, false);
                    return new outgoing(view);

            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            int swi=0;
            if(chatList.get(position).getSender()== FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
            {
                swi=1;
            }
            else
            {
                swi=0;
            }
            return swi;


        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

            SingleChatList chat=chatList.get(listPosition);

            if (chat != null) {
                int swi=0;
                if(chat.getSender()== FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                {
                    swi=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    swi=0;
                }
                switch (swi) {
                    case 0:
                        ((incoming) holder).message.setText(chat.getMsg());
                        ((incoming) holder).time.setText(String.valueOf(chat.getTimestamp()));

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        ((outgoing) holder).message.setText(chat.getMsg());
                        ((incoming) holder).time.setText(String.valueOf(chat.getTimestamp()));
                        break;

                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return chatList.size();
        }
    }
```

Here, I am deciding viewtype using following logic

```
senderuid== FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

If above condition is true then it should be an outgoing message.

I run above code, but nothing changes for all messages only incoming msg layout is applying

Comment: onBindViewHolder function use  holder.getItemViewType() for getting viewtype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using return for every case.Assigning a value to a local variable and then returning that at the end is considered a good practice. Methods having multiple exits are harder to debug and can be difficult to read.Also you are returing null as viewholder at the end.Try this updated code and check this works.

```
public class MultiViewTypeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private List<SingleChatList> chatList;
int total_types;

public class incoming extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView message, time;

    //public CircleImageView dp;
    public incoming(View view) {
        super(view);
        message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp_text);
    }
}

public class outgoing extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView message, time;
    //public CircleImageView dp;

    public outgoing(View view) {
        super(view);
        message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_text_view);
        time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp_text_view);
    }
}

public MultiViewTypeAdapter(List<SingleChatList> data) {
    this.chatList = data;
    total_types = chatList.size();
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int swi = 0;
    if (chatList.get(position).getSender() == FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()) {
        swi = 1;
    } else {
        swi = 0;
    }
    return swi;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = null;
    View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        case 0:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.msg_incoming_bubble, parent, false);
            holder = new incoming(view);
            break;
        case 1:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.msg_outgoing_bubble, parent, false);
            holder = new outgoing(view);
            break;
    }
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

    SingleChatList chat = chatList.get(listPosition);
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            if (chat != null) {
                ((incoming) holder).message.setText(chat.getMsg());
                ((incoming) holder).time.setText(String.valueOf(chat.getTimestamp()));
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (chat != null) {
                ((outgoing) holder).message.setText(chat.getMsg());
                ((incoming) holder).time.setText(String.valueOf(chat.getTimestamp()));
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chatList.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `viewHolder.getItemViewType()` inside `onBindViewHolder`

try below code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

   SingleChatList chat=chatList.get(listPosition);
   switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
      case 0:
          incoming incommindHolder= (incoming ) holder;
          //TODO Bind data view Holder
          incommindHolder.message.setText(chat.getMsg());
          incommindHolder.time.setText(String.valueOf(chat.getTimestamp()));
          break;

      case 1:
          outgoing outGoindHolder= (outgoing) holder;
          //TODO Bind data view Holder
          outGoindHolder.message.setText(chat.getMsg());
          outGoindHolder.time.setText(String.valueOf(chat.getTimestamp()));
          break;
   }
}
```

**Note:** Please learn about java naming convention mate :)